# Cassandra Java driver showing consistency level as null

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

In my Cassandra Java driver code, I am creating a query and then I print the consitency level of the query

```
val whereClause = whereConditions(tablename, id);         cassandraRepositoryLogger.trace("getRowsByPartitionKeyId: looking in table "+tablename+" with partition key  "+partitionKeyColumns +" and values "+whereClause +" fetch size "+fetchSize)

    cassandraRepositoryLogger.trace("where clause is "+whereClause)
    cassandraRepositoryLogger.trace(s"consistency level ${whereClause.getConsistencyLevel}")
```

But the print shows taht consistency level is null. Why? Shouldn't it be One by default?

```
2020-06-10 07:16:44,146 [TRACE] from repository.UsersRepository in scala-execution-context-global-115 - where clause is SELECT * FROM users WHERE bucket=109 AND email='manu.chadha@hotmail.com';
2020-06-10 07:16:44,146 [TRACE] from repository.UsersRepository in scala-execution-context-global-115 - getOneRowByPartitionKeyId: looking in table users with partition key  List(bucket, email) and values SELECT * FROM users WHERE bucket=109 AND email='manu.chadha@hotmail.com';
2020-06-10 07:16:44,146 [TRACE] from repository.UsersRepository in scala-execution-context-global-115 - consistency level null <-- Why is this null?
```

The query if build like follows

```
def whereConditions(tableName:String,id: UserKeys):Where= {
    QueryBuilder.select().from(tableName).where(QueryBuilder.eq("bucket", id.bucket)) 
      .and(QueryBuilder.eq("email", id.email))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how  getConsistencyLevel method is implemented. This method returns consistencylevel of the query or null if no consistency level has been set using setConsistencyLevel.